# Function is printing twice - any suggestions?

Tags: posts, wp-query, functions, shortcode

My function is returning the results correctly, but for whatever reason it is returning them twice. Any suggestions? It's for a shortcode that queries and lists custom post types matching custom taxonomies.

```
function useful_tools_list($atts){
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'type'      => '',
            'desc'      => '',
            'ul'        => '',
            'li'        => '',
            'merge_tag' => '',
            'value'     => '',
            'tags'      => '',
         ), 
        $atts
    );
    
    $results = '';
    if (($atts['merge_tag']) && (!preg_match('/\b'.$atts['value'].'\b/', $atts['merge_tag']))) {
        $results .= '';
    } else {
        $all_terms = get_terms('types');

        foreach($all_terms as $term) {
            wp_reset_query();
            if (($atts['type']) && ($atts['type'] != "")) {
                $args = array('post_type' => 'useful-tools',
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'types',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => $term->slug,
                        ),
                    ),
                    'types' => $atts['type'],
                    'tag' => $atts['tags'],
                 );
            } else {
                $args = array('post_type' => 'useful-tools',
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'types',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => $term->slug,
                        ),
                    ),
                    'tag' => $atts['tags'],
                 );
            }

            $loop = new WP_Query($args);
            if($loop->have_posts()) {
                if ((!$atts['type']) || ($atts['type'] == "")) {
                    $results .= '<h2>'.$term->name.'</h2>';
                }
                if (($atts['ul']) && ($atts['ul'] == "true")) {
                    $results .= '<ul class="tools-type-ul">';
                }
                while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
                $postID = get_the_ID();
                $desc = '';
                $actualDesc = get_post_meta($postID, '_post_desc', true);
                if ($atts['desc'] == 'true' && $actualDesc != '') {
                    $desc = ' - '.get_post_meta($postID, '_post_desc', true);
                }
                if (($atts['li']) && ($atts['li'] == "true")) {
                    $results .= '<li><a href="'.get_post_meta($postID, '_post_url', true).'">'.get_the_title().'</a>'.$desc.'</li>';
                } else {
                    $results .= '<a href="'.get_post_meta($postID, '_post_url', true).'">'.get_the_title().'</a>'.$desc.'<br>';
                }
                endwhile;
                if (($atts['ul']) && ($atts['ul'] == "true")) {
                    $results .= '</ul>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
add_shortcode('useful-tools', 'useful_tools_list');
```

EDIT: Also tried this, which also outputs the correct results, but outputs twice.

```
$all_terms = get_terms('useful-tools');
        
        foreach($all_terms as $term) {
            wp_reset_query();
            if (($atts['type']) && ($atts['type'] != "")) {
                $args = array('post_type' => 'useful-tools',
                    'types' => $atts['type'],
                    'tag' => $atts['tags'],
                 );
                
            }
```

Comment: Your post you're using this on wouldn't happen to have 2 terms? e.g. 2 categories or a category and a tag? How are you using it?

Comment: A category and a tag, yes.

Comment: Try outputting the contents of $all_terms to screen so you can see how many instances it has in it. As Tom suggests, you may have more terms in your results than you think. If there is more than one instance, you will get more than one foreach loop.

Comment: $all_terms only outputs once. It's definitely in the query as $args outputs twice before looping. I have a custom post type called "useful-tools," which has a custom taxonomy called "types", and tags.

Comment: I only have 3 posts with different types and tags for testing. My shortcode: `[useful-tools type="videos" ul="true" li="true" tags="mental-health"]` should only output a single post, which it does, but outputs it twice.

Comment: If it were me debugging this I would create a counter variable before the foreach loop, e.g. $count=0; Then increment it ($count ++;) at the end of the foreach section. Then dump/print the value of count at different stages of your code between them, just cut/paste and work your way down. Hopefully you will be able to find the part of the code that is looping twice and work back from there? Does this help?

Comment: I tried doing `$count=0; foreach($all_terms as $term) { $count ++; $results .= $count;` and it's returning "1 [result]" and then "2 [same result]" No matter where I put the $count++, it returns the same thing.

Comment: Okay, I figured out that it is outputting the result for the amount of types that are assigned to the post. For example, the post has been assigned types "video" and "activity" with tags: "mental-health" and "teens." I'm only searching for videos, so it only shows me videos, but since there are two types, I'm seeing it twice. If I remove one or add one, I get it once or three times. How can I get it just once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After realizing that I was trying to use the same shortcode for two different types of lists, it was easier to just separate them in two different shortcodes.

To list all posts and break them up by type:

```
/**
 * Shortcode for listing all tools matching tags
 * Usage: [useful-tools-all desc="true" li="true" tags="health, teens"]
 * Alternative PHP Usage: useful_tools_listall(array(desc => 'true', li => 'true', 'tags' => 'health, teens' ))
 */
function useful_tools_listall($atts){
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'desc'      => '',
            'li'        => '',
            'tags'      => '',
         ), 
        $atts
    );
    
    $results = '';
    $all_terms = get_terms('types');

    foreach($all_terms as $term) {
        wp_reset_query();

        $args = array('post_type' => 'useful-tools',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'types',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $term->slug,
                ),
            ),
            'tag' => $atts['tags'],
         );

        $loop = new WP_Query($args);
        if($loop->have_posts()) {
            $results .= '<h2>'.$term->name.'</h2>';
            if (($atts['li']) && ($atts['li'] == "true")) {
                $results .= '<ul class="tools-type-ul">';
            }
            while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

                $postID = get_the_ID();
                $desc = '';
                $actualDesc = get_post_meta($postID, '_post_desc', true);
                if ($atts['desc'] == 'true' && $actualDesc != '') {
                    $desc = ' - '.get_post_meta($postID, '_post_desc', true);
                }
                if (($atts['li']) && ($atts['li'] == "true")) {
                    $results .= '<li><a href="'.get_post_meta($postID, '_post_url', true).'">'.get_the_title().'</a>'.$desc.'</li>';
                } else {
                    $results .= '<a href="'.get_post_meta($postID, '_post_url', true).'">'.get_the_title().'</a>'.$desc.'<br>';
                }

            endwhile;
            if (($atts['li']) && ($atts['li'] == "true")) {
                $results .= '</ul>';
            }
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
add_shortcode('useful-tools-all', 'useful_tools_listall');
```

And to list posts without breaking them up by type (and without repeating them for each type):

```
/**
 * Shortcode for listing tools by type and tags
 * Usage: [useful-tools-only type="documents" desc="true" ul="" li="true" merge_tag="{:3:value}" value="B" tags="health, teens"]
 * Param "type" must be the taxonomy's exact slug name, not the display name, and it is case-sensitive
 * Params "ul" and "li" set to "true" if you want to include <ul> and <li> tags. 
 * Keep "ul" empty and set "li" true when using in Gravity Form confirmation.
 * Params "merge_tag" and "value" are for conditional components in Gravity Form confirmation.
 */
function useful_tools_listonly($atts){
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'type'      => '',
            'desc'      => '',
            'ul'        => '',
            'li'        => '',
            'merge_tag' => '',
            'value'     => '',
            'tags'      => '',
         ), 
        $atts
    );
    
    $results = '';
    if (($atts['merge_tag']) && (!preg_match('/\b'.$atts['value'].'\b/', $atts['merge_tag']))) {
        $results .= '';
    } else {
        
        $myposts = get_posts(
            array(
                'showposts' => -1,
                'post_type' => 'useful-tools',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'types',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $atts['type'],
                    )
                ),
                'tag' => $atts['tags'],
            )
        );

        if ((!$atts['type']) || ($atts['type'] == "")) {
            $results .= '<h2>'.$atts['type'].'</h2>';
        }
        if (($atts['ul']) && ($atts['ul'] == "true")) {
            $results .= '<ul class="tools-type-ul">';
        }
        
        foreach ($myposts as $mypost) {
            
            $postID = $mypost->ID;
            $desc = '';
            $actualDesc = get_post_meta($postID, '_post_desc', true);
            if ($atts['desc'] == 'true' && $actualDesc != '') {
                $desc = ' - '.get_post_meta($postID, '_post_desc', true);
            }
            if (($atts['li']) && ($atts['li'] == "true")) {
                $results .= '<li><a href="'.get_post_meta($postID, '_post_url', true).'">'.$mypost->post_title.'</a>'.$desc.'</li>';
            } else {
                $results .= '<a href="'.get_post_meta($postID, '_post_url', true).'">'.$mypost->post_title.'</a>'.$desc.'<br>';
            }
            
        }
        
        if (($atts['ul']) && ($atts['ul'] == "true")) {
            $results .= '</ul>';
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
add_shortcode('useful-tools-only', 'useful_tools_listonly');
```

Thanks for your help @t2pe and @Tom.